# spring boot send objects,files in one request with angular frontend

Tags: spring, file, object

I need to send files and objects in one request..

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('title', "safd");
formData.append('underTitle', "safd");
formData.append('price', 300);
formData.append('discount', 0);
formData.append('category', "safd");
formData.append('underCategory', "safd");
formData.append('brand', "safd");

if (this.images) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
    formData.append('images', this.images[i]);
  }
}
```

///not working part (cant send object in formdata, and also modelattribute cant read objects)

```
if (this.nod) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.nod.length; i++) {
    formData.append('productSizes', this.nod[i]);
  }
}
```

this.nod is array of object..

Spring

```
@PostMapping("/createProduct")
public String createProduct(@ModelAttribute AddProductRequest addProductRequest) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(addProductRequest);
    return "0";
}
```

With requestbody i can send also objects, but cant send files... And oposite with ModelAttribute (i can send files, but cant send objects)

Is any solution for this?
Or do I have to solve this by adding one more request?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the backend code like the below one, MultipartFile is used to receive files like image, video etc..

```
 @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

And in html file include the below code

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" max-size="2000">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: not the problem, i have MultipartFile inside AddProductRequest class